# Bounding box of a thick line with end caps

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have been pulling my hair out on the trigonometry on this and just can't seem to get it right.

Basically, I need to calculate the bounding box of a line going from point (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) where the line has a thickness of w (centered on the line) and an end cap -- that is to say a half circular projection centered on each endpoint, with a radius of w/2.

This is all in a flat 2 dimensional plane. I need it to generate a clip path for redrawing items under a moving line.

I am looking for the smallest rectangle that will enclose this line for all values of x1, y1, x2, y2 and w.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean the bounding box with sides aligned with the coordinate axes then it is $$[\min(x_1,x_2)-\tfrac{w}{2}, \max(x_1,x_2)+\tfrac{w}{2}] \times [\min(y_1,y_2)-\tfrac{w}{2}, \max(y_1,y_2)+\tfrac{w}{2}].$$

Comment: Thanks but no, I mean the rectangle one of whose sides is at angle atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the distance from the first point to the second:

$$d = \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$$

If $d$ is small then simply use a bounding box as given in my comment.  Otherwise compute a vector of length $w/2$ pointing from the first point to the second

$$a = (a_1, a_2) = \left(\frac{w\,(x_2-x_1)}{2d}, \frac{w\,(y_2-y_1)}{2d} \right)$$

Compute a vector that is orthogonal to $a$ by turning it ninety degrees counter clockwise (also of length $w/2$):

$$b = (b_1, b_2) = (-a_2, a_1)$$

Now the four vertices of the bounding box are given by:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
c_1 &=& (x_1 - a_1 + b_1, y_1 - a_2 + b_2)\\
c_2 &=& (x_1 - a_1 - b_1, y_1 - a_2 - b_2)\\
c_3 &=& (x_2 + a_1 - b_1, y_2 + a_2 - b_2)\\
c_4 &=& (x_2 + a_1 + b_1, y_2 + a_2 + b_2)
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: Do you know what should be done to add z axis for this?